# PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException:..) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, playback, video-player

I tried to play video using .m3u8. However, when the video that was running on IOS runs on Android, an error appears The error code looks like this.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.prepareExtraction(HlsMediaChunk.java:495)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:468)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:437)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:394)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4469):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

E/flutter ( 4469): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

And this is my code.

- Android permission

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:label="flutter_example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

- is this my Flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(const VideoApp());

/// Stateful widget to fetch and then display video content.
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoApp({super.key});

  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse('https://video.pokabook.kr/518713/index.m3u8?scale=1080p'))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          child: Center(
            child: _controller.value.isInitialized
                ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

If you know about PlatformException or Playback error, please let me know

I've tried many ways, but I can't find one, so I'm writing